# SSRS on EC2 vs SSRS on RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reporting-services, amazon-rds

I have been looking around for the best practices when setting up Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) in AWS(Amazon Web Services) environment. We have two options

1. SSRS on EC2: We can launch an EC2 instance with SQL Server installed on it and then we can setup SSRS using Report Server Configuration Manager.
2. SSRS on RDS: We can add an option group for SSRS in RDS and that will enable the SSRS on RDS instance. We can set the limit of max memory % usage for SSRS while setting up SSRS option in RDS

I am looking for comparison between SSRS on EC2 vs SSRS on RDS in terms of security, performance or any other limitations/benefits of using any of these two options.

Answer (score 1):

The entire reason AWS strived to provide SSRS support is due to the cries from Dev's.

I shouldn't take all the credit as MSFT China Support helped me get it going, <strike>manually</strike> **automagically** setting up SSRS on an EC2 prior to RDS offering the service.
Here is the script I wrote and if you take a look it's worth paying for the RDS service. If there is only one reason you go SSRS RDS, it's ease of use.

Before you read this answer, keep in mind I have SQL Reporting Server baked into an Amazon Machine Image (AMI). I can't have an Auto Scale Group (ASG) with a server that requires a 45minute install in its UserData (Bootstrap script).

Hence I have a pre-installed SSRS image and then restore the Reporting Config database over the top during the deployment. Here are the issues with that:

[RSConfig generates a Dsn Connection String doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55998961/rsconfig-generates-a-dsn-connection-string-doesnt-work)

Resort to what I did if there's a blocker, take it as a Plan B. I've walked the path before...