# How to detect System.Management.ManagementException "not supported"?

Tags: c#, system.management

We have some code to counter the brightness dimming on laptops.
It relies on System.Management calls.
It works fine on a laptop but on a PC without power management it throws an Exception: *System.Management.ManagementException "not supported"*
I do not want to make it work (for that see [System.Management.ManagementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247659/system-management-managementexception)), but want to just detect the case that it is not supported and then exit early to avoid having the exception thrown.
Is there a way to do so?

I tried looking for the same or similar issues on stackoverflow and the rest of the internet.

Currently I'm using try catch to handle this, but would prefer not having to rely on that.

```
System.Management.ManagementScope s = new System.Management.ManagementScope("root\\WMI");
System.Management.SelectQuery q = new System.Management.SelectQuery("WmiMonitorBrightness");
System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher(s, q);
try {
  System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection moc = mos.Get();
  foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject o in moc) { // exception here
  ...
```

actual: System.Management.ManagementException "not supported"

expected: should test support earlier and exit if not supported

Comment: Controlling monitor brightness is notoriously fickle.  Judging from the many questions about it, it just seems to not be commonly implemented by the video driver supplier.  No workaround, avoid relying on it.